# Confusion about conditional expression in AWK

Tags: awk, gawk

Here is my input file:

```
$ cat abc
0   1
2   3
4   5
```

Why does the following give a one-column output instead of a two-column one?

```
$ cat abc | awk '{ print $1==0?"000":"111" $1==0? "222":"333" }'
000
333
333
```

Shouldn't the output be the following?

```
000 222
111 333
111 333
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `awk` is going to parse this as:

```
awk '{ print ($1==0) ? "000" : (("111" $1==0) ? "222" : "333") }'
```

That is, when it prints the three zeros, it doesn't even consider the rest of the operation.  And when it doesn't print the three zeros, it prints the triple threes because `"111"` concatenated with any string is not going to evaluate to zero.

You probably want to use:

```
awk '{ print ($1==0?"000":"111"), ($1==0? "222":"333") }'
```

where the comma puts a space (OFS or output field separator, to be precise) in the output between the two strings.  Or you might prefer:

```
awk '{ print ($1==0?"000":"111") ($1==0? "222":"333") }'
```

which concatenates the two strings with no space.

Comment: why not `($1==0?"000 222":"111 333")` ?

Comment: @Kent: I suspect that the context will change and two separate conditions are required.  However, in the restricted context of this question, your simplification would also work — but it evades the problem.  And understanding the problem is more important than the circumvention chosen.

Comment: make sense...  btw I would write `if {}...` statement if the logic is complex, instead of nesting `bool?foo:bar`

Comment: There are lots and lots of possible rewrites.  Mine kept the two conditionals but neutered them so `awk` would not misunderstand what the OP wanted — choosing two different possibilities.  Methinks the second condition might be `$2 > 2` or something, but it was just `$1 == 0` again for simplicity here.